# $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}k$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation, binomial-theorem

I cant wrap my head around simplifying the following sum:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}k,$$
>   where $0<x<1$.

I tried to apply standard formulas [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html).

Comment: Use $$\binom {n}{k}=\frac nk \binom {n-1}{k-1}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(ax+1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(ax)^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$
then with differentiating respect to $a$ we have
$$nx(ax+1-x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{k-1}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}k$$
now let $a=1$.

Comment: That's really clever!

Answer (score 1):

If you see that what you have is the expected value of the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with n trials probability of success $x$ for any given trial, then we can answer using probabilistic rules.

The binomial distribution is the sum of $n$ independent [Bernoulli Distributions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDistribution.html) of probability of success $x$ in this case. The expected value of any one Bernoulli distribution is $x$. So we have that your sum is equivalent to

$$\underbrace{x+x+x+\cdots+x}_{n\text{ times}} = nx$$

Via the law of the expected value of the sum of random variables.